# PdfShuffler and Unity

Tags: 16.04, unity, pdf

I have installed PdfShuffler on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (then with unity desktop) and got a very basic interface with

> file : add, save as, quit
>
> edit : rotate left, rotate right, crop, delete
>
> view : zoom in, zoom out
>
> help : about

I find the project smart and would like to exploit it, but it seems that I cannot merge several .pdf documents within a single file (and also the rotated thumbnails do not hold as such). Is there any way to do this ? (possibly with PDF-Shuffler), Thanks.

Comment: "Add" followed by "Save as"?

Comment: @pomsky "Save as" seems not to work. Is it a current issue with Unity ?

Comment: Sorry, no clue :( I use neither Unity nor 16.04. Works fine here on 17.10 GNOME, pdfshuffler version 0.6.0.

Comment: Can somebody explain this downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very strange, it works as expected on:

- 14.04 LTS with Xfce;
- 16.04 LTS with MATE DE and Unity;
- 17.10 with GNOME;
- 18.04 LTS with MATE DE.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install PDF-Shuffler
2. Launch PDF-Shuffler
3. Click *Add*
4. Select all PDF-files (from `/usr/share/cups/data/` in my case)
5. Shuffle, rotate their thumbnails
6. Click *Save as*
7. Open saved document.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update and reinstall PDF-Shuffler and tell you.

Comment: After having that done, I get the same drawback